# Laravel redirect back as a link

Tags: php, laravel-4

We usually use `Redirect::back()` inside a controller to do a redirection to the last visited page but, is there a Laravel function to use in the views as a link?

Comment: Because of the apparent inability (or unwillingness) to do a simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+link+back+view).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the helper:

```
{{ URL::previous() }}
```

So you could do this:

```
<a href="{{ URL::previous() }}">Go Back</a>
```

Comment: Mmh, that is returning me to the homepage everytime

Comment: Are you sure you are coming from a different url? You need to another page, then you need to load this page via a link from that page.

Comment: Yeah that must be it, I'm changing the url to trigger a 401 error page, where the link will be. It will never be my case so I need to use something else, but the answer would be correct, thanks

Answer (score 0):

an alternative

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="{{ route('home') }}">Back to Home</a>
```

Comment: Please, for more quality add more details about your answer.